# How to implement callback/selector with performSelector in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to create an equivalent of below method signature (Objective-C) in swift language.  I couldn't get an answer on how to get the right equivalent for this.  Any help is highly appreciated.

```
- (void)myMethod:(MyObject*)firstParam
                        setCallbackObject:(id)obj
                        withMySelector:(SEL)selector {
    [obj performSelector:selector withObject:nil afterDelay:0]
}
```

Comment: In Swift, functions are just named closures, so you can pass the function around by name!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First:

[NOTE](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html)

> The performSelector: method and related selector-invoking methods are not imported in Swift because they are inherently unsafe.

*If you still want to implement it that way, read below.*

---

You could use `NSTimer`:

```
var myTimer: NSTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.0, target: self, selector: "selectorMethod", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

*String can be used where `Selector` is needed. It will automatically be converted (autoboxing).*

*The delay can be of course higher: 0.1 is then equal to 1 tenth of a second.*

To call a method like:

```
func selectorMethod() {
    ...
}
```

---

We need to check before using the selector on the class. But the `respondsToSelector:` is in the `NSObject` protocol, so you have to derive at least from that (or one that subclasses from it).

To make it clear, here is the example.

#### Code:

```
class Test {
    func myMethod(firstParam: String, setCallbackObject obj: AnyObject, withMySelector selector: Selector) {
        if obj.respondsToSelector(selector) {
            var myTimer: NSTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.0, target: obj, selector: selector, userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
            myTimer.fire()
        } else {
            println("Warning: does not respond to given selector")
        }
    }
}

class Test2: NSObject {
    func selectorMethod() {
        print("worked")
    }
}

var test: Test = Test()
var callBackObj: Test2 = Test2()
test.myMethod("thisfirstis", setCallbackObject: callBackObj, withMySelector: Selector("selectorMethod"))
```

#### Output:

> workedProgram ended with exit code: 0

Comment: Updated the answer with example code. Maybe it wasn't clear enough, if I get downvoted :-(